# Asp.Net Core 2.0 Web Application Static Files Gives 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-core, http-status-code-404

I try to get custom-extension static files from my web-server (asp.net core 2.0).

I try to run next:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDirectoryBrowser(); // just to see that I have this files 
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseDirectoryBrowser();
    }
}
```

So, I can see my files at folders but I can't get it - it throw 404:
[image: my file in folder]

And when I click on it: nothing happened and I got 404.
[image]

**Updated for Evk:**

I added static_json.json file to static files at src folder and it get it as expected:
[image: But red one still not available]

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Is this application IIS hosted?

Comment: @kuskmen Yes, just run it via debug. Just default project. Didn't change webroot folder location etc...

Comment: Where are the files you are trying to serve? UseStaticFiles() will serve by default files on wwwroot. If you are trying to serve files in a different folder, look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?tabs=aspnetcore2x#serve-files-outside-of-web-root

Comment: So your question implies files with non-"custom" extensions do work? Like .txt files for example?

Comment: @jpgrassi Yes, I use default folder: wwwroot/src. As you can see browser detected this files like static content but it doesn't want to return it (and just throw 404)

Comment: @Evk I updated question for you.

Comment: I think there was configuration of IIS to serve custom extensions files. It was called something like Mime i think or MYM dont remember precisely..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure, but it looks like your extension is denied by IIS settings to access directly as a static resource. Please, try this for the web.config:

```
<configuration> 
   <system.webServer> 
       <security> 
          <requestFiltering> 
              <fileExtensions> 
                <add fileExtension=".appinstaller" allowed="true" /> 
              </fileExtensions> 
         </requestFiltering> 
       </security> 
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Also check request filtering. See more information:
[How to deny access to a specific file name extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/fileextensions/add)

Answer (score 20):

I had the problem during development.
I used the overloaded method of UseStaticFiles to set the option ServeUnknownFileTypes to true.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()
        .UseSession()
        .UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
        })
        .UseDirectoryBrowser()
        .UseRequestLocalization()
        .UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer might come in late, but in my case the solution was in my IIS settings.
JavaScript file extension (.js) is set to False in Allowed column of Request Filtering.
Removing js file from Request Filtering solved this case for me.